# Mailkit - fetch & search not returning new mails after a while

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, imap, mailkit

For some time I was using an IMAP-subscribe/event MailKit based solution to gather & identify new mails which worked reliably. Suddenly a strange behaviour appeared: the first few events were fired but then MailKit seemed not to receive any new CountChanged events - even though the connection remained online.

So I tried to switch to a simple sleep-60 loop that fetches all mails in the inbox which worked - for some iterations. After a few minutes the fetch command did not return new mails anymore. The system behaves like there is a cache that is not updated after a while so MailKit always receives the same results - for both, event-based as well as polling-fetch/search methodology. I do not know whether there have been changes to the Exchange system.

Does anyone have a clue what the reason for this behaviour could be or in what directions I continue my investigations?

MailKit 2.1.3.0, Exchange version couldn't be determined

Comment: I would recommend using MailKit's ProtocolLogger feature to get a log of what is going on. My guess is that the caching issue is the server, not MailKit (hint: MailKit doesn't keep a cache).

Comment: "but then … seemed not to receive" sounds as if a substandard NAT middlebox has started dropping packets silently.